# SweetAlert seguir execução

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Tenho o `confirm` abaixo usando `SweetAlert`. Se o usuário clica no cancelar ele para a execução e volta para a página anterior corretamente. Mas se clica no continuar, ele não faz nada. Como posso fazer para ele seguir a execução do script ao clicar no continuar?

Detalhe: não é dentro do `isConfirm` mas sim "fora" dele, pois tem outras funções abaixo dele....

```
               sweetAlert({
                  title: "Tem certeza?",
                  text: "KM muito alta: <?php echo $km_retorno - $km_inicial; ?>. Se estiver errada pressione Cancelar!",
                  type: "warning",
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
                  confirmButtonText: 'Continuar',
                  cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
                  closeOnConfirm: false,
                  closeOnCancel: false
                  },
                  function (isConfirm) {
                   if (isConfirm) {
                    //aqui deveria sair daqui e seguir a execução
                   } else {
                     sweetAlert({
                       title: "Erro!",
                       text: "Operação cancelada!",
                       type: "error"
                     },
                     function () {
                       window.location.href = 'InformaKM.php';
                    });
                  }
               });
```

**UPDATE**

Conforme solicitado, abaixo desse `alert` segue esse código. Sei que não é a forma correta de chamar o `SweetAlert`, mas estou corrigindo isso.

```
    //TESTA SE FOI TENTADO PASSAR O FORMULÁRIO EM BRANCO (UM CAMPO É SUFICIENTE PARA TESTE, POIS TODOS SÃO DEPENDENTES
    if  (empty($km_inicial) || ($km_inicial == 0)) {
                ?>
                  <html>
                    <head>
                      <script src="sweet/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
                      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweet/dist/sweetalert.css">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                      <script>
                       sweetAlert({
                             title: "Erro!",
                             text: "Operação não permitida!",
                             type: "error"
                          },
                          function () {
                            window.location.href = 'InformaKM.php';
                       });
                      </script>
                    </body>
                   </html>
                <?
                exit;
    }

    //TESTA SE FOI TENTADO PASSAR KM NA SAIDA DA EMPRESA.
    if  (!empty($km_retorno) && (!empty($update))) {
                ?>
                  <html>
                    <head>
                      <script src="sweet/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
                      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweet/dist/sweetalert.css">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                      <script>
                       sweetAlert({
                             title: "Erro!",
                             text: "KM somente deve ser informada no retorno!",
                             type: "error"
                          },
                          function () {
                            window.location.href = 'InformaKM.php';
                       });
                      </script>
                    </body>
                   </html>
                <?
                exit;
    }
    /*
     *
     * INICIA O TESTE PARA SABER SE SERÁ FEITO UPDATE OU INSERT
     *
     */

    /*
     * Verifica se é saida da empresa
     *
    */

    if (!empty($update)) {

        /* VERIFICA SE A PORTARIA NÃO REGISTROU ALGUM OUTRO RETORNO DO
        *  MESMO VEICULO NO MESMO DIA OU SE ESTÁ REGISTRANDO A SAIDA DE
        *  RESERVA MAIS DE UMA VEZ
        */
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as flag FROM RESERVAS
                  WHERE
                  DATA_RETORNO_REAL = '0000-00-00' AND
                  ATIVA = '1' AND
                  COD_VEICULO = :veiculo AND
                  DATE_FORMAT(DATA_SAIDA, '%d-%m-%Y') = :data_reserva AND
                  KM_INICIAL = :km_ini and
                  km_inicial > 0 and
                  ultimo_editor = 'portaria'";

        $data = $conexao->prepare($query);    // Prepara a query para execução
        $data->bindParam( ':km_ini', $km_inicial);
        $data->bindParam( ':veiculo', $veiculo);
        $data->bindParam( ':data_reserva', $data_reserva);
        $data->execute();// Executa(run) a query
        $data2 = $data->fetch();
        $flag = $data2['flag'];
   if ($flag == 0)  { //SE NÃO TEM RESERVA ABERTA OU SAIDA DUPLICADA

       $sql = "UPDATE reservas r SET r.km_inicial = :km_inicial, ultimo_editor = :user, ultima_atualizacao = now()  WHERE r.cod = :reserva";
       $stmt = $conexao->prepare( $sql );
       $stmt->bindParam( ':km_inicial', $km_inicial);
       $stmt->bindParam( ':user', $username);
       $stmt->bindParam( ':reserva', $reserva);

       $result = $stmt->execute();

      //VERIFICA SE RETORNOU ERRO
      if ( ! $result ) {
        var_dump( $stmt->errorInfo() );
        exit;

      } else { //SE INSERIU CORRETAMENTE
            ?>
              <html>
                <head>
                  <script src="sweet/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
                  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweet/dist/sweetalert.css">
                </head>
                <body>
                  <script>
                   sweetAlert({
                         title: "Sucesso!",
                         text: "Saida da Empresa Confirmada! Nº <? print($reserva); ?>.",
                         type: "success"
                      },
                      function () {
                        window.location.href = 'InformaKM.php';
                   });
                  </script>
                </body>
               </html>
            <?
            return;
      } //FECHA ELSE INSERÇÃO

     } ELSE { //SE A SAIDA DA EMPRESA JÁ ESTÁ REGISTRADA OU TEM OUTRO REGISTRO ABERTO DO MESMO VEICULO.
            ?>
              <html>
                <head>
                  <script src="sweet/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
                  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweet/dist/sweetalert.css">
                </head>
                <body>
                  <script>
                   sweetAlert({
                         title: "Erro!",
                         text: "Existem registros abertos para esse veiculo.\nSistema bloqueado!",
                         type: "error"
                      },
                      function () {
                        window.location.href = 'js/logout.php';
                   });
                  </script>
                </body>
               </html>
            <?
            exit;
} //FECHA ELSE VERIFICAÇÃO DE RESERVA ABERTA OU SAIDA DUPLICADA

/*
 *
 * É RETORNO para a empresa
 *
 *
*/
} ELSE {

    //TESTA SE ESTA INFORMANDO KM EM UMA RESERVA QUE NÃO SAIU AINDA.
    $query = "select r.km_inicial from reservas r where r.ativa='1' and r.cod  = '".$reserva."'";
    $data = $conexao->prepare($query);
    $data->execute();
    $row=$data->fetch();

    if ($row['km_inicial'] == 0) {  //SE A SAIDA ESTÁ CORRETA FAZ O UPDATE COM A KM DA ULTIMA SAIDA.

            ?>
              <html>
                <head>
                  <script src="sweet/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
                  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweet/dist/sweetalert.css">
                </head>
                <body>
                  <script>
                   sweetAlert({
                         title: "Erro!",
                         text: "Reserva não saiu da empresa. Verifique!",
                         type: "error"
                      },
                      function () {
                        window.location.href = 'InformaKM.php';
                   });
                  </script>
                </body>
               </html>
            <?
            exit;
    }

   $sql = "UPDATE reservas r set r.km_final = :km_retorno, r.data_retorno_real = curdate(), r.hora_retorno_real = curtime(), ultimo_editor = :user, ultima_atualizacao = now() WHERE r.cod = :reserva";
   $stmt = $conexao->prepare( $sql );
   $stmt->bindParam( ':km_retorno', $km_retorno);
   $stmt->bindParam( ':reserva', $reserva);
   $stmt->bindParam( ':user', $username);

   $result = $stmt->execute();

   //VERIFICA SE RETORNOU ERRO
   if ( ! $result )      {
        var_dump( $stmt->errorInfo() );
        exit;

   } else { //SE INSERIU CORRETAMENTE

            ?>
              <html>
                <head>
                  <script src="sweet/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
                  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweet/dist/sweetalert.css">
                </head>
                <body>
                  <script>
                   sweetAlert({
                         title: "Sucesso!",
                         text: "Retorno Nº <? print($reserva); ?> confirmado!",
                         type: "success"
                      },
                      function () {
                        window.location.href = 'InformaKM.php';
                   });
                  </script>
                </body>
               </html>
            <?

   } //FECHA ELSE INSERÇÃO

} //FECHA ELSE PRINCIPAL
?>
```

Comment: Aqui funcionou corretamente, coloquei um alert dentro do if do isConfirm

Comment: @JuniorNunes sim, ele executa o que estiver dentro do isConfirm, mas preciso que ele "saia" quando clicado no continuar, pois tem outras funções abaixo dele, entende?

Comment: Tenta chamar uma das funções que estão abaixo dentro do isConfirm, acho que funciona.

Comment: @Fred ele está dentro de um PHP, ele realmente precisar "sair" para continuar. Tem testes de variáveis, outros alerts e por fim um update...

Comment: @Diego como assim "sair", e o que exatamente tem abaixo do sweetAlert? tu não consegue colocar o bloco de código abaixo dentro de uma função e chamar no isConfirm? Você também pode fechar o sweetAlert ao confirmar mudando isso aqui: `closeOnConfirm: false` pra true

Comment: Mas se você tem coisas abaixo deste sweetalert, ele vai executar mesmo clicando ou não no "Confirmar", o javascript não vai esperar nada ser executado do sweetalert. Ele será assincrono. A melhor forma de se fazer é você criando uma function e colocando ela dentro do isConfirm e também você tem que mudar o closeOnConfirm para true (como o @JuniorNunes escreveu), assim o seu alert será fechado. Se realmente não for possível fazer da forma que estamos falando, poste o restante do seu código ou um exemplo bem próximo do que você quer para pensarmos outra forma. Assim está pouco dificil te ajudar

Comment: Adicionei o codigo abaixo do alert...